# Create graph panel with multiple query

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have the following monitoring stack:

- collecting data with telegraf-0.12
- storing in influxdb-0.12
- visualisation in grafana (3beta)

I am collecting "system" data from several hosts and I want to create a graph showing the "system.load1" of several host NOT merged. I though I could simply add multiple queries to the graph panel.

When creating my graph panel, I create the first serie and see the result but when I add the second query, I got an error.

Here is the [panel creation with 2 queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLR7m.png)

Here is the query generated by the panel:

```
SELECT mean("load1") FROM "system" WHERE "host" = 'xxx' AND time > now() - 24h GROUP BY time(1m) fill(null) SELECT mean("load1") FROM "system" WHERE "host" = 'yyy' AND time > now() - 24h GROUP BY time(1m) fill(null)
```

And the error:

```
{
  "error": "error parsing query: found SELECT, expected ; at line 2, char 1",
  "message": "error parsing query: found SELECT, expected ; at line 2, char 1"
}
```

So I can see that the generated query is malformed (2 select in one line without even a ';') but I don't know how to use Grafana to achieve what I want.
When I show or hide each query individually I see the corresponding graph.
I have created a similar graph (with multiple series) with chronograf but I would rather use grafana as I have many more control and plugins...

Is there something I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading couple of thread in github issues, here is a quick fix.
As mentionned by @schup, the problem and its solution are described here:
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4533

The binaries are currently not fixed in grafana-3beta (if might in the next weeks). So there are 2 options: fixing the source and compile or patched an existing install.

I actually had to patch my current install:

```
/usr/share/grafana/public/app/app.<number_might_differ_here>.js

sed --in-place=backup 's/join("\\n");return k=k.replace/join(";\\n");return k=k.replace/;s/.replace(\/%3B\/gi,";").replace/.replace/' app.<number_might_differ_here>.js
```

Hope this might help (and that it will soon be fixed)

Comment: Well done Jerome, you've saved my day! Still using v2.6 and your answer fixed the problem. Now I can use DERIVATIVE as well! `SELECT DERIVATIVE(mean("bytes_recv"),1s) AS Rcvd FROM "net" WHERE "interface" = 'eth0' AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null);` with a second query for the `bytes_sent`. Great work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an API change in influxdb 0.11
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4533

Comment: You're right, I should have been more careful when searching answers for this... thx